# Pass multiple selected value and text as an array javascript

Tags: javascript, multiple-select

I have select field from where I can select multiple data. Now I want to access that value as key and value like array.

```
let selected_size = $(this).find(":selected").map(function(i, el) {
    var value = $(el).val();
    var text = $(el).text();
}).get();
```

I want to access the select value like this:

```
[1=>red,2=>green]
```

The numbers will be the actual value of color.

I tried to do:

```
let selected_size = $(this).find(":selected").map(function(i, el) {
     var value = $(el).val();
     var text = $(el).text();
     return [value=>text]
}).get();
```

But this does not seem to work.

Comment: can you add your html code?

Comment: JavaScript does not support arrays with named indexes. You can use objects instead and the syntax is `{[value]: text}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, **Objects** are usually used to store Key / value pairs.
Here's an example using JS's [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
$("select[multiple]").on("input", function() {

  const data = $(this).find(":selected").get().reduce((ob, el) => {
    ob[el.value] = el.textContent;
    return ob
  }, {});
  
  console.log(data);

});
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2">Blue</option>
  <option value="3">Green</option>
</select>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```